# With Augeas, how can i modify the value of an attribute, using the current value?

Tags: augeas

Let's say I have some generic INI-type file, covered best by the Samba.lns. I have an entry like:

```
attribute = value
```

And I want to *transform* `value` to `Some-VALUE-x`. For a more concrete example:

```
augtool> print /files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir
/files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir = "/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever"
```

And I want to change the value to:

```
"/var/cache/yum/noarch/$releasever"
```

That is, I want to replace `$basearch` with `noarch` and leave the rest alone. My actual example is a little more complex.  Can I even do this within augeas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single Augeas API call, but with aug_get and aug_set you can do it in the calling language. e.g. using ruby-augeas:

```
aug.set("/files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir", aug.get("/files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir").sub("$basearch", "noarch"))
```

If you're using augtool per your example, in shell you could do:

```
cachedir=$(augtool get /files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir | sed 's/$basearch/noarch/')
augtool set /files/etc/yum.conf/main/cachedir "$cachedir"
```

Comment: What about extending the given lns to add labels in a way so that values are represented as child nodes?

Comment: Splitting up the value into more child nodes makes sense sometimes, particularly when a setting has multiple values (e.g. an array of values), but for this file path it would seem excessive for little gain. It isn't generally useful, only for this one use-case. Splitting the path by "/" would indeed allow you to set and replace one component.

Comment: I need to figure out if it makes sense to extend a lens to do this. The actual example is an INI-like file whose RHS contains a comma-separated list of paths.

Comment: Yes, that's very common, and makes much more sense than the provided example. e.g. the Subversion module/lens splits `global-ignores` and other properties into separate nodes by whitespace or commas.

Comment: I just noticed the `Shellvars_list` stock lens which does something very very close to what I need. Adding an answer to hilight this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The `Shellvars_list` stock lens comes close to providing what I needed.

Given a file such as

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vgroot/lvswap rd.lvm.lv=vgroot/lvroot"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

I want to append arbitrary values in an idempotent way to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. This lens parses this file as follows:

```
augtool> print $v
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TIMEOUT
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TIMEOUT/quote = ""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TIMEOUT/value = "5"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DEFAULT
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DEFAULT/quote = ""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DEFAULT/value = "saved"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU/quote = ""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU/value = "true"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT/quote = "\""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT/value = "console"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/quote = "\""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[1] = "crashkernel=auto"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[2] = "rd.lvm.lv=vgroot/lvsap"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[3] = "rd.lvm.lv=vgroot/lvroot"
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY/quote = "\""
/files/home/c14027/default-grub-sample/GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY/value = "true"
```

We'll do a `defvar` in augtool so that `$v` represents our prefix.

Add a new value to this `CMDLINE` paramater:

```
set $v/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[last()+1] test=142
```

Remove existing ones:

```
rm $v/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[. =~ regexp("^test=.*")]
```

Replace the key-pair whose key is `test=`:

```
set $v/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/value[. =~ regexp("^test=.*")] test=1234
```